# Changing the order of finite double summations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, solution-verification

Let $I = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ with two indices $i, j$. Then can we do the following:

$$\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} a_j = \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} \sum_{i = 1} a_i = (n - 1)[a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n]?$$

Although the outer sum is dependent on the inner sum's index, I still think we can do this change of order in the above summation. Am I wrong?

Here's my proof:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} a_j & = \sum_{i \in I} a_1 + \dots + a_{i - 1} + a_{i + 1} + \dots + a_n \\
& = [0 \cdot a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n] + [a_1 + 0 \cdot a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n] + [a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{n - 1} + 0 \cdot a_n] \\
& = (n - 1) \cdot \sum_{i \in I} a_i
\end{align}
as for specific values of $i$, we can omit undefined terms like $a_{n + 1}$ or $a_0$. The last equality comes from noting that $\sum_{i = 1} ^ {n} \alpha = \alpha \cdot n$, where $\alpha$ is any scalar.

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: In the question, you have taken the index set $I$ for but the sums while in your proof you have taken  $\mathcal{I}$ for the outer sum. Is it a typo?

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA Yeah, it was typo. Thanks!

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{i \in I} a_1 + \dots + a_{i - 1} + a_{i + 1} + \dots + a_n = [a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n] + [a_1 + a_3 + \dots + a_n] + [a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n]?$

Comment: I expand the sum $\sum_{i \in I}$ and so every square brackets term is for different values of $i$. So, for the first term, I take $i = 1$ and keep only the $a_i$'s that are defined e.g., omit $a_0$ or $a_{n + 1}$

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA Sorry I forgot to mention you in my previous comment.

Comment: Hint: When you write it with the $j$ summation first, what value of $i$ are you going  to omit in the $j$ summation?

Comment: @NickD I don't think I have to omit any terms. It'd be like $\sum_{i = 1} ^ {n} 5 = 5 n$, right?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the notation makes no sense: what does $\sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} \sum_{i = 1} a_i$ mean?

Comment: E.g. if $I={1,2,3}$, the first sum is $(a_2 + a_3) + (a_1 + a_3) + (a_1+a_2)$. What does the second sum look like if you expand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\sum_{i \in I} a_i$.  Then 
$$\sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}}a_j=A-a_i\\
\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} a_j = \sum_{i \in I} \left(A-a_i\right)=nA-A=(n-1)A$$
Your interchange of summations does not work because in the second version $i$ is a dummy variable in the inner summation so the outer summation cannot reference it.

It would be more usual to write your double sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{\substack{j=1\\j \neq i}}^n$$

Answer (score 3):

This has already been hinted at, but 
$$\sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} \sum_{i \in I} a_i$$
does not mean what you think it means. It means you have an inner sum
$\sum_{i = 1} a_i$ that is always the same,
and an outer sum over some set $I \setminus\{i\}$ where $i$ is some externally-defined variable that has no particular relationship to the $i$ in the inner sum.
(This is already confusing, isn't it? 
That's the first reason why this is a bad idea.)
So depending on whether this externally-defined $i$ satisfies $i\in I$ or 
$i \not\in I,$ you add up either $n-1$ or $n$ copies of the inner sum.

The correct way to switch the order of the sums is
$$\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} a_j 
= \sum_{j \in I} \sum_{i \in I \setminus \{j\}} a_j. $$
Notice that the subscript is still $j$ on the right-hand side of the equation;
if you also change the subscript to $i$, all you've done is to write the exact same sum using different choices of dummy variables.

It turns out that switching the order of summation actually does help, because
$$ \sum_{i \in I \setminus \{j\}} a_j = (n - 1)a_j $$
when $j \in I,$ and now we sum these terms over $j \in I$ to get
$$ \sum_{j \in I}  (n - 1)a_j =  (n - 1) \sum_{j \in I} a_j
 =  (n - 1) \sum_{i \in I} a_i.$$